Clipping raster by bounding box with gdal
I've been trying to clip a raster file(.tif) with gdal. But getting Error: "Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero".  Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code ?
Edit : Below are my GetGeoTransform() and GetGeoProject() outputs of my tif file, in case it's needed.
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 44N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",81],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32644"]]
from osgeo import gdal, osr

fn_input = r'path\File.TIF'

fn_extent = 'path/clip_extent.tif'

utm11_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
utm11_srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84")
utm11_srs.SetUTM(11,1)

bounds_utm = (78.54760607220511, 11.670880584988538, 78.58386873862227, 11.649485363749173)

gdal.Warp(fn_extent, fn_input, outputBounds=bounds_utm, outputBoundsSRS=utm11_srs)


Have you checked that the area you are selecting does overlap the raster file? What is the extent of the raster?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104362/how-to-get-extent-out-of-geotiff

Your bounding box is not in utm but is in degrees
